# How to compile Google protobuf in 64 bit compiler?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to use google protubuf in my MFC project in C++. The problem is that my project is 64 bit (x64) and there is not any DLL or LIB in 64 bit version.
What to do?

Comment: Compile it from sources
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md